# Apply font changes to Enhanced Message Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, msgbox

Renaud Bompuis pulled together some [great code](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/05/20/ms-access-enhanced-message-box-replacement/). I want to put in font changes (e.g. bold) on a field result within the `Dialog.RichText` format.

I'm trying to get the result of `CaptureEmail` to be bold. The box just makes `CaptureEmail` bold.  The value doesn't show up.  If I remove the `<strong>` from the code, the email shows up, but not bold.

```vb
Private Sub Other_Email_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  ' https://www.devhut.net/2016/08/18/validate-e-mail-addresses/

Dim ClickResult As VbMsgBoxResultEx
Dim CaptureEmail
Dim html
CaptureEmail = Me.Other_Email

If CaptureEmail = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf CaptureEmail > 0 Then
    If ValidateEmail(Me.Other_Email) = False Then

        ClickResult = Dialog.RichBox("The inputted e-mail " & _
          <strong>[CaptureEmail]</strong> & _
          " does not appear to be a valid Email_Address. " & "<p/>" & _
          "Would you like to recheck it before adding it?", _
          vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Invalid Entry", , , 0, False, False, False)
        If (ClickResult = vbYes) Then
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf (ClickResult = vbNo) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf ValidateEmail(Me.Other_Email) = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is the concatenation of the first argument supplied to the `RichBox` method:

```
"The inputted e-mail " & <strong>[CaptureEmail]</strong> & " does not appear to be a valid Email_Address. " & "<p/>" & _
"Would you like to recheck it before adding it?"
```

Since `<strong>` & `</strong>` are literal strings, they should be included as part of the content of the strings that are surrounded by double-quotes, e.g.:

```
"The inputted e-mail <strong>" & CaptureEmail & "</strong> does not appear to be a valid Email_Address. "
```

You also have some malformed HTML here:

```
"<p/>"
```

Presumably, this should be:

```
"<p>The inputted e-mail <strong>" & CaptureEmail & "</strong> does not appear to be a valid Email_Address.</p>" & _
"<p>Would you like to recheck it before adding it?</p>"
```

---

You also seem to be mixing data types -

You initially assign the value of the form control `Other_Email` to your variable `CaptureEmail`:

```
CaptureEmail = Me.Other_Email
```

And you then treat `CaptureEmail` as an integer:

```
If CaptureEmail = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf CaptureEmail > 0 Then
```

However, based on the content of the message box, it would imply that `CaptureEmail` actually contains a string:

> The inputted e-mail **" & **CaptureEmail** & "** does not appear to be a valid Email_Address.

---

A few other observations about your code:

```
If CaptureEmail = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf CaptureEmail > 0 Then
```

Given that you only wish to proceed when `CaptureEmail` is greater than zero, only test is required:

```
If CaptureEmail > 0 Then
    ...
End If
```

Similarly, later in the code, you have the following:

```
If ValidateEmail(Me.Other_Email) = False Then
    ...
ElseIf ValidateEmail(Me.Other_Email) = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Since `ValidateEmail` returns a boolean value with only two possible values, it is not necessary to test both since if the return is not `False`, then it must be `True` and vice-versa.

As such, the code may become:

```
If Not ValidateEmail(Me.Other_Email) Then
    ...
End If
```

The same logic could be applied here:

```
If (ClickResult = vbYes) Then
    Cancel = True
ElseIf (ClickResult = vbNo) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Since, for any result other than `vbYes`, you aren't performing any action.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood correctly and it helps, you want "Would you like to recheck it before adding it?" to be bold as well.

Then you need to encapsulate the same between the tags`<strong></strong>`

The same way [CaptureEmail] is in between those tags in your code